# Read XML Document using C# or Java

Tags: c#, java, xml, xml-parsing

I want to read below XML format only some attributes are required not All.
For E.g.:

```
<Parts>
-   <Part>
        <Section>3003512</Section> 
        <Mark>RP-103</Mark> 
        <Length>4950</Length> 
        - <Components>
                <Section>3003512</Section> 
                <Mark>RP-103</Mark> 
                <Length>4950</Length>
                <Remark>System Generated </Remark>
              <Components />
            <Remark>No Comments </Remark>
        </Part>

-   <Part>
        <Section>3003512</Section> 
        <Mark>RP-103</Mark> 
        <Length>4950</Length> 
        <Components />
        <Remark>No Comments </Remark>
     </Part>
</Parts>
```

I want to Read Only Sections and Mark in Tabular Format. I am using below code to read this But it is giving Error Table Schema 'Component' Already Exists .

```
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        DataColumn dc = new DataColumn("Mark");
        DataColumn dc1 = new DataColumn("Sections ");
        dt.Columns.Add(dc); 
        dt.Columns.Add(dc1);
        DataSet dSet = new DataSet();


        if (File.Exists(xmlpath2))
        {

            XmlTextReader Reader1 = new XmlTextReader(xmlpath2);



            dSet.ReadXml(Reader1, XmlReadMode.Auto);


            for (int i = 0; i < dSet.Tables[0].Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                DataRow rows = dSet.Tables[0].Rows[i];
                DataRow myRow = dt.NewRow();
                myRow["Mark"] = rows["Mark"];
                myRow["Sections "] = rows["Sections "];

                dt.Rows.Add(myRow);
            }


            GridView1.DataSource = dt;
            GridView1.DataBind(); 

        }
```

Comment: There are several XML libraries that can assist in this. Try searching more, then come back and ask.

Comment: Make up you mind-- Java or C## since the answers given will vary drastically depending on this choice.

Comment: What is with all the redundant 'white space' lines in the source.  Is it supposed to make the code go faster?

Comment: rows["Sections "] does not match to your <Section> tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an example using [LINQ to XML](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387098.aspx):

```
var ele = XElement.Parse(xml); // change to XElement.Load if loading from file

var result = ele.Descendants("Section")
                .Zip(ele.Descendants("Mark"), 
                    (s,m) => new {Section = s.Value, Mark = m.Value});
```

Now you can create your `DataTable`:

```
var table = new DataTable();
var marks = new DataColumn("Mark");
var sections = new DataColumn("Sections");

table.Columns.Add(marks);
table.Columns.Add(sections);

foreach (var item in result)
{
    var row = table.NewRow();
    row["Mark"] = item.Mark;
    row["Sections"] = item.Section;
    table.Rows.Add(row);
}
```

This will produce:

```
Mark     Sections 
RP-103   3003512 
RP-103   3003512 
RP-103   3003512
```

It assumes that each `Section` is followed by a single and corresponding `Mark`. It also requires `System.Xml.Linq` and `System.Linq`.

Comment: Code is working fine . Thank you .Please Let me know how can I bind Three Values from XML document in Below code. var result = ele.Descendants("Section")
                .Zip(ele.Descendants("Mark"), 
                    (s,m) => new {Section = s.Value, Mark = m.Value});

Comment: @kuldeepverma I've updated the answer to show how to create the `DataTable`. No more help from here.

Comment: Thank you , i've already done this . But I am not able to bind more Columns .<Length>4950</Length> into data table.

Answer (score 0):

was doing something simiar a while back:
[LINQ multiple columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8601074/linq-multiple-columns)

hope should get you on the right track